# This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

When I visit my home it displays my homepage but when I try to login, this
is the page I get or when I go to other page or redirect the page to any page I get the same error.

[image: picture]

**php.ini**
[image]

My folder permission is  755 and I change it to 777 and still get the same result.

**.htaccess**

```
Deny from all
```

I don't know why but all of the `.htaccess` is `Deny from all` in the system, the system work in my co-employee's machine.

Comment: What's your Controller File name ? For eg if your controller is product then it's file name should be :"Products.php" and same way the class name should also be the same.

Comment: the controllers filename is hri.php, if i try to capitalized the first letter the system will error. i dont think the problem is in the system because it work in my co-employee's machine. but in my machine it's http error 500.

Comment: what error is given if you are Using "Hri.php" instead of hri.php ?

Comment: Here's the error message if i try to rename the filename.
"Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid."

Comment: Post the content of `routes.php` and the content of `hri.php` so we can help you figure this out.

Comment: @たぬき thank you for your reply sir, i really appreciate it, but i cant disclose the code here. What i am concern about is the same system is working with my co-employee's machine and in my computer its not working. I'm not sure if all the module required in this system has been enabled or the rewrite mod has been enable that is why i post my php.ini also.

Answer (score 0):

I already fix it by enabling the short_open_tag from php.ini

```
short_open_tag = On
```